# What's the disadvantage of mt_rand?

Tags: php, random, rounding

What's the definition of bias in:

> The distribution of [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32.

If it's the kind of bias stated in [alternate tie-breaking rules for rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Alternating_tie-breaking), I don't think it really matters (since the bias is not really visible).

Besides `mt_rand()` is [claimed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to be four times faster than `rand()`, just by adding three chars in front!

Assuming `mt_rand` is available, what's the disadvantage of using it?

Comment: "just by adding three chars in front" changes it from one function call to another, which works entirely differently. Why would it surprise you that it goes three times faster? Would it have been more convincing if they'd named the function `really_fast_rand()`? ;-)

Comment: There are none. mt_rand is just another function that is much better than the old function at producting random-ish-numbers

Comment: @Spudley I mean.. that's a joke

Comment: @Pacerier - I thought it was.... that's why I put a winky smily at the end of my comment.  :)

Comment: @Spudley lol ok, even :)

Comment: Wait. If mt_rand has 3 more characters in front of it, doesn't that mean it would end up executing 3 times slower? The syntax parser has to process those 3 extra characters. Just saying... ;)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`mt_rand` uses the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) algorithm, which is far better than the [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) typically used by `rand`. For example, the period of an LCG is a measly 2<sup>32</sup>, whereas the period of mt_rand is 2<sup>19937</sup> − 1. Also, all the values generated by an LCG will [lie on lines or planes](http://web.archive.org/web/20140801002727/http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/) when plotted into a multidimensional space. Also, it is not only practically feasible, but relatively easy to determine the parameters of an LCG. The only advantage LCGs have is being  potentially slightly faster, but on a scale that is completely irrelevant when coding in php.

However, `mt_rand` is **not suitable for cryptographic purposes** (generation of tokens, passwords or cryptographic keys) either.

If you need cryptographic randomness, use [`random_int`](http://php.net/random_int) in php 7. On older php versions, read from `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` on a POSIX-conforming operating system.

Comment: For a visual representation of the difference: [link](http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/)

Comment: @JamesAlday Great link! Added it to the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is only available from PHP 5.3. (another good reason to make sure you're on the latest php release)

Comment: To confirm, your answer means there is **no** advantage in rand() over mt_rand(), and rand() should be deprecated, right?

Comment: @Pacerier LCGs are faster than Mersenne Twister, so if you don't care about the quality of randomness at all (for example, if you want to show one of 6 random pictures on the frontpage of your website), `rand` is still adequate. Therefore, it's unlikely to be deprecated, but you're right in that if you care about the quality of randomness, you should use `mt_rand`.

Comment: @phihag wait I'm getting confused, isn't `mt_rand` supposed to be 4 times faster than the algorithm used by `rand` ?

Comment: @Pacerier The php doc says so, but conveniently fails to compare to a specific algorithm and architecture. Mersenne twister is really fast, and since you're programming in php anyways, any supposed speed difference doesn't really matter anyway. You're right in that **there is no reason to use `rand` over `mt_rand`** unless you want to use the precise implementation of a specific glibc on an embedded system or a very special scientific simulation.

Comment: Linkrot on the "lie on lines or planes", sadly.

Comment: @Kzqai Thanks for the notice; fixed.

Comment: @JamesAlday the image in the link no longer seems to work, could not find a similar site  :-(

Comment: Yeah, and I'm not even sure now what the original image looked like! But I think that [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230210/is-mt-rand-more-secure-than-rand) has some nice images that get the point across...

Comment: The image in [the link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140801002727/http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/) works fine for me.

Comment: Is it okay if I edit in an update about `random_int()`? :)

Comment: Updated with `random_int`.

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is *not* a secure PRNG. See [this guide](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) for more information and instructions on how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 9):

The distribution quirk that you quoted is only relevant when the random number range you're generating is larger than 2^32. That is 4294967296.

If you're working with numbers that big, and you need them to be randomised, then perhaps this is a reason to reconsider using `mt_rand()`. However if your working with numbers smaller than this, then it is irrelevant.

The reason it happens is due to the precision of the random number generator not being good enough in those high ranges.

I've never worked with random numbers that large, so I've never needed to worry about it.

The difference between `rand()` and `mt_rand()` is a lot more than "just three extra characters". They are entirely different function calls, and work in completly different ways. Just the same as you don't expect `print()` and `print_r()` to be similar.

`mt_rand()` gets it's name from the "Mersene Twister" algorithm it uses to generate the random numbers. This algorithm is known to be a quick, efficient and high quality random number generator, which is why it is available in PHP.

The older `rand()` function makes use of the operating system's random number generator by making a system call. This means that it uses whatever random number generator happens to be the default on the operating system you're using. In general, the default random number generator uses a much slower and older algorithm, hence the claim that `my_rand()` is quicker, but it will vary from system to system.

Therefore, for virtually all uses, `mt_rand()` is a better function to use than `rand()`.

You say "assuming `mt_rand()` is available", but it always will be since it was introduced way back in PHP4.

Comment: Isn't it true that `rand` uses libc and not the *system default/selected* ?

Comment: @Pacerier - libc is what I meant; the point is that it makes a call to a library that is external to PHP, and therefore out of the control of PHP in terms of quality/speed/etc.