# is mt_rand() more secure than rand()

Tags: php

Yesterday I overheard a conversation about `rand()` and `mt_rand()`, a collegue said that both of these are predictable and you should use different functions? I was wondering, I know `rand()` is predictable in some way, and after some googling. Even `mt_rand()` seems to be predictable if I readed this correctly.

For this I wrote a small piece of code, which creates an image:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(512, 512) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
for ($y = 0; $y < 512; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < 512; $x++) {
        if (rand(0, 1)) {
            imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $white);
        }
        else{
            imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $black);
        }
    }
}
imagepng($im); imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

this code outputs this image, as you can see it has some kind of pattern:
[image: rand() image]

while the `mt_rand()` function gave me this output:
[image: mt_rand() image]

now my question is, is `mt_rand()` really that predictable, it seems pretty random to me compared to the `rand()` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808021/whats-the-disadvantage-of-mt-rand

Comment: What do you mean by *secure* in this case? Do you mean in the sense that the value can't be predicted?

Comment: This method is much better than to print random numbers 10000 times and to count them.

Comment: Both `rand` and `mt_rand` are ***pseudo*** random number generators, which by their very definition are predictable under certain circumstances (e.g. you get to know their seed or internal state). For truly unpredictable random numbers you need a hardware generator. OS-level implementations which maintain an entropy pool fuelled by more or less random events and/or an actual hardware RNG are much more random than such PRNGs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php):

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

`mt_rand` generates *better* random numbers than `rand`, and much faster. But that doesn't make it "secure" in the sense that it should be used for cryptography. Whether it's secure enough for your application is pretty subjective.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing.  No idea who DV'd this or why.

Comment: By "secure" we don't know if the user means cryptography.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No, we don't.

Comment: Let's say I use `mt_rand()` for generating a salt, would it be insecure?

Comment: @Azrael Why are you doing that instead of using an existing, proven solution?

Comment: Because existing/proven solutions might also be known to be cracked.

Comment: @Azrael That's a terrible reason to write your own solution. Existing/proven solutions are going to be *fixed*, and orders of magnitude harder to crack than anything you're going to write yourself. I don't want to discourage experimentation, but you really absolutely *must* not attempt to write your own cryptographic libraries for production systems. It is one of the very hardest things to get right, with the highest stakes, and existing battle-tested solutions are abundant.